# Break nested object retrieval in linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a type called `Employee`, which has a list of `Alignments` (`List<Alignment>`) . An `Alignment`, in turn, has a `Manager`, which is an `Employee` object. So, I have a potential infinitely nested relationship.

When I try to retrieve a list of all employees, I also want a list of their Alignments, and, in the Alignments, I want the Manager. However, I don't want the Manager's Alignments.

Below is a stripped down version of what I'm trying to do.

```
MyEntities db = new MyEntities()

db.Employees
.Select(x => new EmployeeModel
{
    DisplayName = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName,
    Alignments = db.Alignments
        .Where(a => a.EmployeeID == x.EmployeeID)
        .Select(y => new AlignmentModel
        {
            Id = y.AlignmentID,
            Manager = new EmployeeModel
            {
                DisplayName = y.Manager.FirstName + " " + y.Manager.LastName
                //,Alignments = null
            },
            Name = y.AlignmentName
        }).ToList()
})
```

The error message I get back is:

> The type 'Employee' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

I realize that it's because the Manager's Alignments are not part of the query, but, if I include them, I run into the problem that the Alignments need to have a Manager, which needs a list of Alignments, etc. etc.

How do I break this dependence on always initializing with the same properties? I can't set the Alignments to null, since I then get another error about the Alignments list having to be initialized and not null.

**------Edit--------**

Sorry about the confusion. I'm using Entity Framework to query a SQL database with Employees and Alignments.

Here are my Employee and Alignment object models in c#, where I want to load the data to (stripped down for simplicity)

```
public class EmployeeModel 
{
    public List<AlignmentModel> Alignments { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public EmployeeModel() {
        Alignments = new List<AlignmentModel>();
    }
}

public class AlignmentModel
{
    public EmployeeModel Employee { get; set; }
    public EmployeeModel Manager { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show you model classes...

Comment: could you provide some sample data

Comment: Confusing: Are you using Entity Framework, or any database? Or do you have local classes Employee and Alignment?

Comment: I added some local classes to, hopefully, make it a little clearer.